Displaying all CDP-disabled interfaces
I have disabled CDP on some ports of Cisco switch, but I can't display those ports in the output of the show cdp interface command. It only shows the interfaces where CDP is enabled and their status is either up or down. How can I find the ports where CDP has been disabled?

The show interface status command will show all the interfaces.

If you can see the ones that have CDP enabled, then all the rest are the ones with it disabled.

That was really the point of my comment. Use the show cdp interface command the the OP has been using, and then compare it to the show interface status command. The interfaces in the results of the latter command that are not in the results of the former command are the non-CDP interfaces.

Thanks for the help. After your tip, I used 'show startup-config | include interface | no cdp enable' which made the process much easier.
